# Datagridview set row bg color if expression is true

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have Order managment desktop application and i show all orders in dgridview.

All orders has three types: `Paid`, `Not Paid`, `In progress`.

So am trying in datagridview list to change bacground color to red only in all rows if order has status type `Not Paid`.  Yellow on all orders where is status `In prigress`...

So does i can inside loop (foreach) with `DataGridViewRow` to check if col value is `Not Paid` red bacground color? Or any other way to set this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `CellFormatting` event.

```
private void DataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // specify the desired column number
    {
        string value = e.Value.ToString();

        if (value == "Not Paid")
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else if (value == "In Progress")
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It working. Just one think i need to do is to check if `e.COlumng.Index != null`. Becouse whidout that i get `NullException`